# make: extract jar if it has not been extracted yet

Tags: makefile

In my project I need a library. To make it available I have to extract a jar file. I want to prepare Makefile to automate this process. I thought I got it right but after all make does nothing regardless of change in the java file (if CMDControl.class exists, otherwise it extracts the jar file every time).

```
all : CMDControl.class

%.class : %.java
    javac $<

CMDControl.class : org/gjt/mm/mysql/Driver.class
    jar xf ../mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar

clean :
    -rm *.class
```

the jar file consists of these directories: com  META-INF  org

What's wrong in the Makefile?

I tried

```
all : CMDControl
CMDControl : CMDControl.class
```

but that did not help either.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with jar. How would you do this by hand? If you had a jar file and several other files, how would you determine whether the jar file had already been unpacked-- without unpacking it?

Comment: @Beta: a jar file is just an archive. When it is extract I should see directories com, META-INF, org in the directory where Makefile is placed. I tried to set a file from this 'expected to be unpacked' jar as a prerequisite but it failed to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that since the jar file isn't a prerequisite of anything, Make doesn't care whether it's been modified.

This should do the trick:

```
%.class : %.java
    javac $<

CMDControl.class : org/gjt/mm/mysql/Driver.class

org/gjt/mm/mysql/Driver.class: ../mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar
    jar xf $<
    touch $@
```

(The last command updates the modification time of `org/gjt/mm/mysql/Driver.class` so that Make will believe that it's up to date.)

Comment: jar gets unpacked every time. date of Driver.class is 6 of September. How to change the Makefile so that only its presence decides on unpacking?

Comment: @lord.didger: ah, I had assumed that `jar` would update the modification dates of the extracted files. Easy to fix...

Comment: indeed, that I could have figured out myself but i didn't :)